# Increase Matlab memory

Tags: matlab

Why does the code below cause Matlab to keep increasing the amount of memory used? Nothing is being stored from one iteration to the next? Yet Matlab keeps using up my system memory until the whole machine grinds to a halt. I am running on windows 7 professional with about 16GB of physical ram.  y is just a 100*1 vector and x a 100*7 matrix of data. The system start to struggle as Matlab gets over 15GB which in understandable what is not so understandable is why Matlab needs so much memory for the program below.

```
clc;
iter=100000000;
b_OIRE=[1,0,1,1,1,1,1];
nsims=2;

for t=1:nsims
    y=y_store(:,t);
    [b_GIREII]=GIREII(y,x,b_OIRE,iter);
end


function [b_GIREII MSE]=GIREII(y,x,b_OIRE,iter)  % [## "iter" denotes the iteration number]
   [n, p]=size(x);
   dim=1;
   b=x\y; 
   b_GIREII=b;

   sigma_sq=((y-x*b)'*(y-x*b))/(n-p);

   econFlag=0;
   [U,sigma,V] = svd(x,econFlag);

   U1=U(:,1:p);
   d=zeros(p,1);
   k=zeros(p,1);

   alpha=V'*b_GIREII;
   Delta=sigma.^1;         % [Error! not sigma.^2 but sigma.^1]
   Delta=diag(Delta);
   f=Delta.*alpha;
   F=diag(f);
   Theta=sum(f);
   c=p^2*sigma_sq+p*Theta^2;
   g=Theta*sum(alpha);
   one=ones(p,1);

   b=F*alpha;
   I=eye(p);
   A=sigma_sq*I+F.^2;
   G=sigma_sq*I+Theta*F;
   H=sigma_sq*I+f*f';

   q=(p-1)/p;

   k1=0;
   k2=0;
   d1=0;
   d2=0;

   for ii=1:p
       k1=k1+alpha(ii)/(q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2);
       k2=k2+1/(q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2);
       d1=d1+alpha(ii);
       d2=d2+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2;
   end

   for ii=1:p
       k(ii)=(Delta(ii)*alpha(ii)^2)/((q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2))-(k1/k2)*(Delta(ii)*alpha(ii)/(q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2));
       d(ii)=(1/p)*(d1/(sigma_sq+d2)*Delta(ii)*alpha(ii)-k(ii));   
   end

   K=diag(k);
   D=one*d';
   b_GIREII= V*(K+D)*U1'*y;
   MSE=(k'*A*k)+(2*k'*H*d)-(2*b'*k)+(p*d'*H*d)-((2*g/Theta)*f'*d)+alpha'*alpha;

   best_GIREII_MSE=MSE;
   best_b_GIREII=b_GIREII;
   best_index=1;

   for jj=1:iter           % [## "iter" denotes the iteration number]
       alpha=V'*b_GIREII;
       Alpha_store(:,jj)=alpha;
       f=Delta.*alpha;
       f_store(:,jj)=f;
       F=diag(f);
       Theta=sum(f);
       c=p^2*sigma_sq+p*Theta^2;
       g=Theta*sum(alpha);
       b=F*alpha;
       A=sigma_sq*I+F.^2;
       A_store(:,:,jj)=A;
       G=sigma_sq*I+Theta*F;
       H=sigma_sq*I+f*f';

       k1=0;
       k2=0;
       d1=0;
       d2=0;

       for ii=1:p
            k1=k1+alpha(ii)/(q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2);
            k2=k2+1/(q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2);
            d1=d1+alpha(ii);
            d2=d2+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2;
       end

       for ii=1:p
            k(ii)=(Delta(ii)*alpha(ii)^2)/((q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2))-(k1/k2)*(Delta(ii)*alpha(ii)/(q*sigma_sq+Delta(ii)^2*alpha(ii)^2));
            d(ii)=(1/p)*(d1/(sigma_sq+d2)*Delta(ii)*alpha(ii)-k(ii));   
       end

       D=one*d';
       K=diag(k);
       b_GIREII= V*(K+D)*U1'*y;
       MSE=(k'*A*k)+(2*k'*H*d)-(2*b'*k)+(p*d'*H*d)-((2*g/Theta)*f'*d)+alpha'*alpha;

       if(MSE<best_GIREII_MSE)
           best_b_GIREII=b_GIREII;
           best_GIREII_MSE=MSE;
           best_index=jj+1;
       end

       if rem(jj,10000000)==0
           disp('10000000 interations complete')
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: what is `y_store` and `x`? Please post a code which can be run directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `GIREII.m`, you are putting following three variables in a loop which runs for `100000000` times.

```
1. Alpha_store(:,jj)=alpha; %%jj goes from 1:10^8
2. f_store(:,jj)=f;
3. A_store(:,:,jj)=A;
```

Interestingly, you are not using either of them. I guess you can just remove them. Please pay attention to the warnings in the MATLAB editor, which are underlined in orange color.

Comment: I would like to also add, that since these variables are growing you are running into horrible memory fragmentation. This also causes lots wasted memory.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like @Rody already found the problem with your code, but in fact it is not hard to track this kind of problem down in general.

Here are the three steps to get there:

1. Turn on `dbstop if error`
2. Wait till the code breaks down, or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> once you see the memory usage growing beyond what you expected, to investigate in the even more general case you could also set a breakpoint.
3. Use `whos` and see whether you either have a huge number of variables, or some huge variables in your workspace.